# Filter by a date condition with an unspecified year in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a data frame that has a "date" column. The format is: "Y%-m%-d%"

```
> class(df$date)
[1] "character"

> head(df$date)
[1] "1989-03-01" "2002-03-24" "2021-04-02" "2004-02-01" "2020-03-26" "1996-04-06"
```

I would like to subset my dataframe, taking out all the dates between [01-01;01-05] (first to fifth january included) **no matter the year**, which is what is causing me trouble.

How can I do that? Thank you very much.

EDIT: it appears that I might have expressed myself badly. I would like to erase from the dataset the period from the 1st to the 5th of January included. So to keep what comes after, the rest of the year, for each year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative, converting to character.

```
df[format(as.Date(df$date), "%m%d") > "0105",]
```

Comment: it gives an unfamiliar error to me: invalid 'trim' argument

Comment: Sorry - I had assumed you converted to `Date` first...I can update answer...

Comment: @Recology See edited answer - converted to `Date` first, before the month-year character value...

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option where we take the `substring` excluding the year part and create a logical vector with `01-01` to `01-05` using `%in%`

```
subset(df, !substring(date, 6) %in% sprintf("01-%02d", 1:5))
```

---

Or may convert to `Date` class and extract the `month`, `day` to create the logic

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
   mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
   filter(month(date) == 1, day(date) > 5)
```

Comment: I might have expressed myself badly in english, because I want to keep in my data frame what comes after the fifth january, sorry. But I will figure it out now I think, thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @Recology try the update

Comment: it is almost good, the problem is that ==1 keeps january only. Let's turn it this way: the output that I am looking for is to keep from XXXX.01.06 to XXXX.12.31 :)

Comment: @Recology isn't that you require the january only?